# Perl unit testing deep structures

Tags: perl, unit-testing

TMTOWTDI, well I sure hope so - I've been using Test::Deep for my last few projects whenever I come across multidimensional hashes (sometimes 4-5 levels deep). Right now my usual practice is just typing out these hashes and filling in my expected data then running `cmp_deeply(actual, expected, msg)`. Does anyone have any advice on unit testing deep nested data like this? - my current method seems grossly inefficient, sometimes taking over a hour per unit test of a data structure.

Comment: Just how big are these data structures? An hour is a huge amount of runtime no matter what size of data you are dealing with.

Comment: @Ether - Could it be because comparison routine is not fully optimized? I have always had to roll my own (due to some fancy needs like comparison tolerances and custom comparison methods) and don't know how good the stock ones are. but I know I was able to drastically optimize mine compared to original versions.

Comment: @DVK: it depends on how you call it. For example, Test::Deep has lots of customization functions (`noclass(), `methods()`, `str()` etc) that let you specify exactly how to compare various parts of an object. But IMHO you should rarely have to roll your own - the only time I have really needed to do so myself was to compare DateTime objects inexactly (e.g. check if they are within N seconds of each other).

Comment: @Ether - does it allow custom per-key comparator routines? And arbitrary nmeric precision (again per-hash-key)?

Comment: @DVK: definitely yes to the latter, as `num()` will do that; for the former, it depends on what you want to do; I'd probably use an API instead to fetch the values in a form suitable for comparisons.

Comment: As far as I understand from the comments, you are asking for a like_deeply() method what would test parts of structure to match specific criteria while skipping most of it. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Test-Simple-0.96/lib/Test/More.pm) and `is_deeply` like the next commenter. I have also somewhat automated comparison by having a t/sample/ directory in which I store the expected values by running the tests by hand and using [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.128/Dumper.pm) where appropriate. (Oh I'd better have gone with [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/YAML-0.72/lib/YAML.pm) -- TMTOWTDI!)

I.e. you run the dump-generator once, review the dumped structures, commit them, and then just rely on `is_deeply` until tests break which means either a bug, or an intended structure change.

Answer (score 2):

I am usually fine with `is_deeply` from [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore) for this purpose. I also used [Test::Differences](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aDifferences) for some projects - it seems to have better output on non-equality.

Answer (score 1):

If you just like to test the structure, try [Data::Validate::Struct](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aValidate%3a%3aStruct).

You need to define a reference data structure to compare against the actual data structure that can be any level deep, any combination of nested hashes/arrays.

Most important to note here, this Module validates the data type, not the actual data.

Ex:

```
my $exp = {
'body' => {
    'results' => [
        {
            'template' => [
                {
                    'origin' => 'word',
                    'name' => 'word',
                    'id' => 'int',
                    'attributes' => [
                       {
                           'value' => 'number',
                           'key' => 'word'
                       },
                       {
                           'value' => 'text' ,
                           'key' => 'word'
                       }
                    ],
                    'hostname' => 'hostname',
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
};
```

and then

```
my $v = new_ok('Data::Validate::Struct', [ $exp ]);
ok($v->validate($act), 'validate an exp against an act' . $v->errstr());
```

would validate the structure of `$act` against `$exp`

Try to have a look at [Tests](https://metacpan.org/source/TLINDEN/Data-Validate-Struct-0.07/t/run.t)  on the Module, i found it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the OP meant the time is consumed by manually typing in the expected values, not by the run time.  If you have a known good structure, you can use Data::Dumper or Data::Dump to generate programmatic text that can then be incorporated into your tests.

Comment: Hi, this is what I mean, sorry for the confusion - I have toyed with Data::Dumper, however most of the times the structure of edge cases is vastly different to a good known structure (and these are the cases I'm usually interested in). Additionally if you use Data::Dumpers output sometimes the data structure will span a few hundred lines , requiring its own file, then your tests need to be segregated unless you want test files spanning thousands of lines :/